# Spring Boot JPA: Many to Many relation as its own class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working with Spring Boot and JPA and I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables. This relationship also needs to have its own attributes, so I had to make this relationship its own class. I also have repositories for all classes. Also, how would I map foreign keys correctly when using non-primitive fields?

My question: How do I realize this so Spring boot does not give me an error? I'm new to both Spring Boot and JPA. Here's a code snippet below:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity //this is a relationship type. Does an annotation for relationship types exist?
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RelationshipType implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Class1 class1;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="code")
    private Class2 class2;


    private Integer anotherNumber;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you've written? "*so Spring boot does not give me an error*" You have not described any error

Comment: Thing is, due to changes I had to make now I get a "class2 does not define an @Idclass" error which obviously needs to get fixed first. I'll edit the post once I have solved that problem and say if the solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look similar to the example below. You need to set the relations to the other tables as `@ManyToOne` to get the desired `@ManyToMany` relation between Employee and Number.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "employees_numbers")
public class EmployeeNumber {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "number_id", nullable = false)
    private Number number;

    @Column(name = "extra_column", nullable = false)
    private String extraColumn;
}
```

Side note: don't use `@NotEmpty` on Integer. It is specifically made for collections.

Side note 2: I'll go on a limp here and say what you want is to add `nullable = false` to the columns and not mark them as `@NotNull`. There is a significant difference between the two.

Comment: I've adopted your changes and added the following annotations to id:

    `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

Now it is saying: `column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Comment: If you want to add bonus fields to a many to many relation you will have to create a separate entity and **insert** and/or **update** it. The reason it's not working for you is probably because you've left `@Embeddable` or some other annotation which may signal to Hibernate that this is an entity which is not to be instantiated, inserted and updated.

Comment: I actually deleted the `@Embeddable` annotation and my annotaation match yours (I still have `@NoArgsConstructor'`) 

Here is the full error-message I'm getting:

Comment: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: de.models.RelationshipType column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Comment: Repeated column means you've added the same column name for different fields. If you don't specify the name attribute of a `@Column` annotation it is going to automatically create it based on how the field is called. If you can edit the question to reflect the current fields of the class I could easily pinpoint the problem. My blind guess would be you put `@Column` on the id field and didn't change the name of the `@JoinColumn(name = "id")`

Comment: So a way to possibly fix this issue is to give each field a name via `@Column` right?

Comment: Via either `@Column` or `@JoinColumn` yes. And the names have to be unique.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm not getting this problem anymore.