# Multiple Entity (Tables) Many to Many relations spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I currently make a RestAPI and struggling in multidirections relation.

Using

```
Java: 20.0.1
Spring Boot: 3.1.1
```

I made the OurUserEntity become primary for the BlackboxEntity and MatingEntity as the foreign.

But then I tried to make the BlackboxParamEntity become primary for the BlackboxEntity and MatingEntity as the foreign, and struggled in this error:`Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for 'com.myplace.projectname.entity.BlackboxParamEntity'`

This is my **application.yaml**

```
spring:
  # autoconfigure:
  #   exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/belajar_spring
    username: postgres
    password: postgres

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          time_zone: GMT+07:00
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

server:
  port: 8081
```

I Have this 4 example of entity codes:

**BlackboxEntity.java**

```
package com.myplace.projectname.entity.blackbox;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.myplace.projectname.entity.OurUserEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.inAppConfig.BlackboxParamEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.side.Status;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "blackbox")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BlackboxEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "blackbox_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private BlackboxParamEntity name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status = Status.WAITING_ENTRY;

    @Column(name = "entrydate")
    private Date entryDate = null;

    @Column(name = "entryBy")
    private OurUserEntity entryBy;

    @Column(name = "revision")
    private int revision = -1;

    @Column(name = "malescounted")
    private int malesCounted = -1;

    @Column(name = "femalescounted")
    private int femalesCounted = -1;

    @Column(name = "blackbox")
    private int blackbox = -1;

    @Column(name = "flyadded")
    private int flyadded = -1;

    @Column(name = "eggharvested")
    private int eggharvested = -1;

    @Column(name = "liveflycount")
    private int liveflycount = -1;

    @Column(name = "deadflycount")
    private int deadflycount = -1;

    @Column(name = "deadflyweight")
    private int deadflyweight = -1;

    @Column(name = "sweight")
    private int sWeight = -1;

    @Column(name = "scount")
    private int sCount = -1;

    @Column(name = "iweight")
    private double iWeight = -1;

    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes = null;

    @Column(name = "enable")
    private boolean enable = true;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_blackbox", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "blackbox_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<OurUserEntity> userEntity = new ArrayList<OurUserEntity>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "blackboxparam_blackbox", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "blackbox_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "blackboxparam_id"))
    private Set<BlackboxParamEntity> blackboxparamentites;

    public BlackboxEntity(
            BlackboxParamEntity name,
            Status status,
            Date entryDate,
            OurUserEntity entryBy,
            double iWeight,
            String notes,
            boolean enable) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.entryDate = entryDate;
        this.entryBy = entryBy;
        this.iWeight = iWeight;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.enable = enable;
    }
}
```

**BlackboxParamEntity.java**

```
package com.myplace.projectname.entity.inAppConfig;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.myplace.projectname.entity.eggfly.BlackboxEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.mating.MatingEntity;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "blackboxparam")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BlackboxParamEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "blackboxparam_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "blackbox")
    private int blackbox;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "blackboxParamEntites", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<MatingEntity> matingentity = new ArrayList<MatingEntity>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "blackboxParamEntites", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<BlackboxEntity> blackboxentity;

    public BlackboxParamEntity(
            int blackbox,
            String name) {
        this.blackbox = blackbox;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**MatingEntity.java**

```
package com.myplace.projectname.entity.mating;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.myplace.projectname.entity.OurUserEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.inAppConfig.BlackboxParamEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.side.Status;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.side.Treatment;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MatingEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "mating_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private BlackboxParamEntity name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "entrydate")
    private Date entryDate;

    @Column(name = "entryby")
    private OurUserEntity entryBy;

    @Column(name = "revision")
    private int revision;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "treatment")
    private Treatment treatment;

    @Column(name = "blackbox")
    private int blackbox;

    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "matingentity")
    private List<ObservationEntity> observations;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_mating", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mating_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<OurUserEntity> userEntity = new ArrayList<OurUserEntity>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "blackboxparam_mating", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mating_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "blackboxparam_id"))
    private List<BlackboxParamEntity> blackboxParamEntites = new ArrayList<BlackboxParamEntity>();

    public MatingEntity(
            BlackboxParamEntity name,
            Status status,
            Date entryDate,
            int revision,
            Treatment treatment,
            OurUserEntity entryBy,
            int blackbox,
            String notes) {

        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.entryDate = entryDate;
        this.revision = revision;
        this.treatment = treatment;
        this.entryBy = entryBy;
        this.blackbox = blackbox;
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```

**OurUserEntity.java**

```
package com.myplace.projectname.entity;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.myplace.projectname.entity.crawlout.CrawloutEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.eggfly.BlackboxEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.mating.MatingEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.prepupae.PrepupaeEntity;
import com.myplace.projectname.entity.side.Role;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OurUserEntity implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "expDate")
    private Date expDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userEntity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<MatingEntity> matingentity = new ArrayList<MatingEntity>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userEntity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<BlackboxEntity> blackboxentity = new ArrayList<BlackboxEntity>();

    public String setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return this.password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried anything like to move the BlackboxParamEntity out from the inAppConfig or make the annotations as similar as OurUserEntity, so it can similarly like the OurUserEntity does.

Comment: I figured out, instead of using ManyToMany, we can use this 
`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.balanced:p)  @JoinColumn(name = "blackboxparam_id", nullable = false)` above the `private BlackboxParamEntity foo;` in BlackboxEntity.java and MatingEntity.java.  Just remove the ManyToMany in those Entities, either in BlackboxParamEntity.

Comment: Referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772300/spring-boot-jpa-many-to-many-relation-as-its-own-class